# Python threading problem for "self.running=Bool"

Tags: python, multithreading, class, self

I want to create camera program for stereo vision. Therefore i think the program for left and right cameras.  Because i want to seperataly work for my cameras. Otherwise program slowdowns and cameras gives low fps. Anyway...

When i tried True state; program start truly but when i pressed stop button program stops there is no problem but not start again when i press start button.

Or i tried None state; program starts there is no problem after  when i press start button  cam window appear   but not stops when i press stop button this time.

```
from threading import Thread
import time
import cv2
import keyboard

class Left_Frame(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.running = False # True or False or None i tried...

    def run(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        while self.running:
            success, img = cap.read()
            cv2.imshow("qwe", img)
            tecla = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFf

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False

    def ss(self):
        self.running=True

left=Left_Frame()

if not left.is_alive():
    left.start()

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('f'):
        left.stop()
        time.sleep(1)

    if keyboard.is_pressed('s'):
        left.ss()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: If you press the `s`key, you shouldn't set the state of your thread to running, you should start it (as far as it's not running already). The start method should set the state to running.

Comment: So, can you explain what must I do?

Comment: Look at your code. It states: `if keyboard.is_pressed('s'): left.ss()`. And the `ss()` function does nothing else than setting `self.running = True`. Instead you should first check if the thread is still running. If so, ignore the pressed key. If it's not running, call `left.start()` again (this can all be done in the function `ss()`). The `run()`method should set `running` to True when it's entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.

```
from threading import Thread
import time
import urllib.request
import cv2
import keyboard


class left_Frame(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.running = True

    def run(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture("http://192.168.137.109/stream")
        state=True
        while self.running:
            # print(state)

            if state==True:
                success, img = cap.read()
                cv2.imshow("left", img)
                tecla = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFf

            if keyboard.is_pressed('f'):
                state = False
                cap.release()
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()

            if keyboard.is_pressed('s'):
                if not state==True:
                    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("http://192.168.137.109/stream")
                    state = True

left=left_Frame()
left.start()
```